# Which payment system has good integration with Java?

Tags: java, api, integration, payment-gateway

At the moment, I am using PayPal to implement my payment process. However, I'm not really happy with the so outdated API that PayPal provides for Java. I have googled for a while and I saw a number of alternatives in several articles such as:

1. [17 paypal alternatives for easier e-commerce.](http://www.webdistortion.com/2010/07/28/paypal-alternatives-e-commerce/)
2. [6 Online Payment Alternatives If You Hate PayPal.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-online-payment-alternatives-hate-paypal/)
3. [5 PayPal alternatives.](http://money.cnn.com/galleries/2008/fsb/0802/gallery.paypal_alternatives.fsb/2.html)

I'd be very grateful if you could give me some opinions on the pros and cons of any of these systems. Besides, based on your experience, please tell me which ones you think has good API for Java developers.

Comment: =( Anyone can give me an idea please?

Comment: Paypal is good and most widely recognized by customers. Just go with it.

Comment: Paypal is also most widely scammed when you don't receive money from verified accounts

Answer (score 10):

[Stripe](http://stripe.com) has a java library and is a very clean and easy payment library to integrate with.

Answer (score 3):

If your average card transaction is £10, you get charged about 50p per transaction with Google Checkout and Paypal... Then the money is transferred to your bank account... The bank charges you an additional 25p per debit card transaction. That makes about 7.5% of your sales if most of your customers spend £10 on debit card. On credit cards the banks charge a bit more.

The problem with online merchant services is that they treat all cards alike - possibly for simplicities sake. The trouble is, most small businesses have customers who pay with Debit cards. Normal card merchant services like Handepay or RMS charge around 20p (fixed) per debit card transaction. Of course the banks still charge you around 25p but still for a debit card you could be paying 45p per transaction instead of 75p on a £10 order.

It gets worse when you have the odd bigger customer. If a customer spends £100 on debit card and you have google/paypal checkout, you'll get charged 3.4% +20p +20p(bank) which is £3.80 to process that order. With RMS or Handepay, since debit cards are a fixed price, it would still only be £0.45. Something to think about if you're a small merchant or most of your customers spend a small amount, or most pay by debit card.

Answer (score 3):

[Recurly](http://recurly.com/) also have very clean and very thorough java integrated API